Can lexical parameters be used in Oracle Discoverer?
I have a question for you. In a Oracle Discoverer report, we can add an additional WHERE clause conditionally, or we can directly obtain values using the get and set structure. However, the values we obtain with this get and set structure can be single values. But I want to be able to get multiple values ​​with get and set. How can I achieve this?
